# group duplicate strings with numeric suffix python

Tags: python, group-by, duplicates

I have a list of strings in mylist

I want to return 2 groups of (animal,animal1,animal04,animal3) and (bird,bird1,bird2)
basically these are duplicates with suffixes
I have a feeling itertool.groupby will be an elegant solution,but couldnt get to it.

I have tried

```
def f(a,b):
    if b.startswith(a):
        return True
    return False

mylist = 'animal animal1 animal04 animal3 bird bird1 bird2 fish insect'.split()
combos = itertools.combinations(sorted(mylist), 2)

for k,v in itertools.groupby(combos,lambda (x,y):f(x,y)):
    print list(v)
```

Result :

```
[('animal', 'animal04'), ('animal', 'animal1'), ('animal', 'animal3')]
[('animal', 'bird'), ('animal', 'bird1'), ('animal', 'bird2'), ('animal', 'fish'), ('animal', 'insect'), ('animal04', 'animal1'), ('animal04', 'animal3'), ('animal04', 'bird'), ('animal04', 'bird1'), ('animal04', 'bird2'), ('animal04', 'fish'), ('animal04', 'insect'), ('animal1', 'animal3'), ('animal1', 'bird'), ('animal1', 'bird1'), ('animal1', 'bird2'), ('animal1', 'fish'), ('animal1', 'insect'), ('animal3', 'bird'), ('animal3', 'bird1'), ('animal3', 'bird2'), ('animal3', 'fish'), ('animal3', 'insect')]
[('bird', 'bird1'), ('bird', 'bird2')]
[('bird', 'fish'), ('bird', 'insect'), ('bird1', 'bird2'), ('bird1', 'fish'), ('bird1', 'insect'), ('bird2', 'fish'), ('bird2', 'insect'), ('fish', 'insect')]
```

The first and third line looks close to my answer but i cant seem to avoid the other 2 extra lines

Accept my gratitude for help or orientation in advance.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `itertools.groupby` is the right tool to use... but here's one solution with regex, using `re.findall`:

```
import re

string = 'animal animal1 animal04 animal3 bird bird1 bird2 fish insect'
mylist = string.split()

items = {}
for i in sorted(mylist):
    matches = re.findall('%s[\d]+' %i, string, re.M)
    if matches:
        items[i] = [i] + matches 

    elif i.isalpha():
        items[i] = [i] # non-alphabetical entries get their own entry

for k in items:
    print(items[k])
```

This prints out:

```
['bird', 'bird1', 'bird2']
['insect']
['animal', 'animal1', 'animal04', 'animal3']
['fish']
```

The pattern will look for all versions of the current word with digit suffixes and return those matches only.

Comment: Yeah this solution is so close only that it misses the "animal" and "bird" entry, the ones without suffixes.Wouldn't mind the fish and insect in output also as far as they are the single list entry.Like I said they are duplicates with suffixes.

Comment: @river_bell Fixed.

Comment: Missed to mention fist time, it's a beautiful solution , neat.Thanks. However When i added a new single entry with "lizard01" to the string, it didn't show up. Sorry for not framing the right question the first time.Right now this might work for me.So thanks again.

Comment: If you add `lizard01` without `lizard`, you won't detect anything. If it works, please consider marking it accepted. Much appreciated.

Comment: Was going to accept anyways :).Do consider further advice if I'm not asking for too much. Happy I learnt a new trick today:)

Comment: @river_bell Sorry if I sounded a bit pushy. :) Glad I could help!